# sql like search character

Tags: mysql

hello i wanted to search after 5 character

```
(yyyy-mm-dd)
2000-02-01
2001-01-01
2001-01-05
2001-03-03
```

i wanted to get mm value

```
 select * from day , employee 
 where Employee.ID = Day.Employee and employee = "$_ID" 
and day.leaveday like "%$month%";
```

The Problem is if i use % % (wildcard) everything like 20001 - 03 - 03 , 2000-02-01, it will show to how i get value mm?

Any ideas? Thanks in advance for any help, and I'm really sorry if this has been asked before

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking it leaveday is a date, datetime, or timestamp column.  If not first make it one since you're storing dates. This will also prevent invalid dates such as 20001 from showing up. Then use the mysql [extract function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract) to run something like this

```
 select * from day , employee where Employee.ID = Day.Employee and employee = "$_ID" and extract(month from day.leaveday)=3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from day , employee 
 where Employee.ID = Day.Employee and employee = "$_ID" 
and MONTH(day.leaveday)="$month";
```